# Is using AutoResetEvent across async block code safe?

Tags: c#

I am trying to lock a section of my code that is synchronous and release the lock in an asynchronous code block (after an execution of a task). I have read about 'AutoResetEvent', and wanted to implement its signaling functionality between the caller and the callee of the code implementation.

The aim is to lock the code that is responsible for verifying whether the transaction was administered before. After the check is done and the transaction was saved, I release the code. The check and saving operations are asynchronous, and the lock release happens at 'continueWith' delegate function.

I have the following abstraction and implementation of AutoResetEvent:

`public interface IThreadLockKeyProvider { public AutoResetEvent PayLock { get;  } }`

```
public class ThreadLockKeyProvider : IThreadLockKeyProvider
{
    public static readonly AutoResetEvent _payLock;

    static ThreadLockKeyProvider()
    {
        _payLock = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    }

    public AutoResetEvent PayLock { get { return _payLock; } }
}
```

The instance is injected as a singleton in .net core dependency injection container.

The code of the eventhandler method is the following:

```
    public Task<Unit> Handle(ProcessPaymentCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { 

        _threadLockKeyProvider.PayLock.WaitOne();

        var res = _brandDepositStrategy.AdministerDeposit().Result; 

        return Task.FromResult(Unit.Value);
    }
```

The AdministerDeposit method that releases the lock.

```
   public override async Task<Task> AdministerDeposit()
    {
        Task<PaymentTransactions> dbOperation = _transactionAdministrationFacade.UpdateDbTransactionAsync(_IPNRequestDto);

        return await dbOperation.ContinueWith(async x =>
        {

            _threadLockKeyProvider.PayLock.Set();

            if (x.IsFaulted)
                throw x.Exception;

            _transactionAdministrationFacade.CallBackDto = await _responseComposer.GetPaymentResponseDto(x.Result, _IPNRequestDto);

            await CreateDepositSF();
        });
    }
```

The question is whether the implementation cause any problems?

Note: The code does work. It doesnt crash and pass the unit tests that I built.

Comment: `ContinueWith` continuations have been deprecated with `async/await`.  Plus the former can lead to shooting oneself in the foot.

Comment: this: `AdministerDeposit().Result;` should really be avoided. 1) It lets the main thread wait for the execution which is basically agains the idea of asynchronous processing. 2) it can be the source of a deadlock, which you really should try to avoid

Comment: Stephen Cleary has an [AsyncAutoResetEvent](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncAutoResetEvent) which I have used. Try it out.

Comment: Mong, thanks for the input. I will consider this. I used it because there was this attribute above the method: [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]. That prevented Async syntax usage. By the way, does that method attribute really work?

Comment: @N0Korrelation it works for synchronous code as long as *all* the things that need to be synchronized are *also* thus decorated; but: it isn't necessarily a *good* way of doing it

Comment: ARE is *not* a lock.  It is only useful as an event, signaling that a blocked thread can start executing again.

Answer (score 2):

in theory there's nothing wrong with `AutoResetEvent` in this scenario, but: it isn't exactly built for async, which means that your `WaitOne()` blocks a thread - exactly what you're trying to avoid. Likewise, you're using sync-over-async. Since this is basically an async lock, seeing the entry/exit so far apart concerns me - it makes it very easy to introduce errors.

Let's try and fix those things:

1. use `SemaphoreSlim` as an async-friendly lock
2. `await` our result
3. move the entry/exit of the lock into the same place

example:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _lock = new(1, 1);

public async Task<int> SomeOuterMethodAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await _lock.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
    try
    {
        var s = await SomeInnerMethodAsync(cancellationToken);
        return s.Length; // just some projection
    }
    finally
    {
        _lock.Release();
    }
}

// note: this could be in unrelated types/instances/etc
private Task<string> SomeInnerMethodAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    => throw new InvalidOperationException("not shown");
```

Comment: It is a possible answer, but not a solution to my answer. I must have the lock release inside SomeInnerMethodAsync, since I may want to exist some of its operations early.